# ChromeSwipeLayout onItemSelected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I tried this guide

https://github.com/ashqal/ChromeLikeSwipeLayout

```
package com.psiphon3.statusactivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.asha.ChromeLikeSwipeLayout;

import static com.asha.ChromeLikeSwipeLayout.dp2px;

public class StatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nameless);

        ChromeLikeSwipeLayout chromeLikeSwipeLayout = (ChromeLikeSwipeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chrome_like_swipe_layout);
        ChromeLikeSwipeLayout.makeConfig()
                .addIcon(R.drawable.selector_icon_add)
                .radius(dp2px(35))
                .gap(dp2px(5))
                .circleColor(0xFF11CCFF)
                .gummyDuration(1000)
                .rippleDuration(1000)
                .collapseDuration(1000)
                .listenItemSelected(new ChromeLikeSwipeLayout.IOnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(int position) {

                    }

                })
                .setTo(chromeLikeSwipeLayout);
    }
}
```

And here's my question:
What code can I use to start a new activity in this code?

```
public void onItemSelected(int position) {

                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(StatusActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
StatusActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i've got a force close